# Mystery Array Object behavior for Array Reversal

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, data-structures, iteration

I'm currently studying data structures and have been exploring javascript.  I've been stuck on this issue with writing an Reverse Array in Place Method.  I've looked at documentation for Array Objects, Object.prototype, and function objects but I can't find the answer to what is going on.  Perhaps I have a logically error, here is the code:

```
//Reverse Array in Place Exercise
Array.prototype.tRev = function()
{
    var nRay = this.valueOf(); //copy current instance of array

    for (var x = 0,y = this.length-1; x < this.length; x++,y--)
    {            
        this[x] = nRay[y];  //switch array element with copy of nRay (original elements)            
    } 
}
```

The method gives me unfamiliar results.

```
var z = [1,2,3,4,5];
var z1 = [343,32423,2434,4,5,5,3];
var z2 = ['hello','hi','goodbye'];

z.tRev();  //console -- > Array [ 5, 4, 3, 4, 5 ]
z1.tRev(); //console -- > Array [ 3, 5, 5, 4, 5, 5, 3 ]
z2.tRev(); //console -- > Array [ "goodbye", "hi", "goodbye" ]
```

To attempt debugging I wrote a couple console.logs to track iterators and array elements in the current instance and copied array.

```
var z = [1,2,3,4,5];
z.tRev();
undefined

 current x is = 1 new copy of y is = 5
 x iterator is = 0 z iterator is = 4
 new x is = 5 old copy of y is = 5

 current x is = 2 new copy of y is = 4
 x iterator is = 1 z iterator is = 3
 new x is = 4 old copy of y is = 4

 current x is = 3 new copy of y is = 3
 x iterator is = 2 z iterator is = 2
 new x is = 3 old copy of y is = 3

 current x is = 4 new copy of y is = 4
 x iterator is = 3 z iterator is = 1
 new x is = 4 old copy of y is = 4

 current x is = 5 new copy of y is = 5
 x iterator is = 4 z iterator is = 0
 new x is = 5 old copy of y is = 5
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's [not a good idea to extend native prototypes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain#Bad_practice_Extension_of_native_prototypes).

Answer (score 0):

```
Array.prototype.tRev = function()
{
    var nRay = this.valueOf(); //copy current instance of array

    for (var x = 0,y = this.length-1; x < y; x++,y--)
    {      var tmp = this[x];      
        this[x] = this[y];  //switch array element with copy of nRay (original elements)  
        this[y] = tmp          
    } 
return this;
}
```

Comment: You can remove the `var nRay` line.

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is that `this.valueOf()` doesn't make a copy of the array. If you want a copy, you should use `this.slice()`. But if you make a copy, then what's the point of doing the reversal in-place?

```
Array.prototype.tRev = function() {
  for (var x = 0; x < this.length / 2; x++) {
    var y = this.length - x - 1;
    var swap = this[x];
    this[x] = this[y];
    this[y] = swap;
  }
}
```

**EDIT: *If you like using ES6:***

```
Array.prototype.tRev = function() {
  for (var x = 0; x < this.length / 2; x++) {
    var y = this.length - x - 1;
    [this[y], this[x]] = [this[x], this[y]];
  }
}
```

Comment: `x < this.length / 2`

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this in O(n/2) time.

```js
var  z = [1,2,3,4,5],
    z1 = [343,32423,2434,4,5,5,3],
    z2 = ['hello','hi','goodbye'];
Array.prototype.tRev = function(){
                         var i = 0,
                           len = this.length,
                         limit = Math.floor(len/2);
                         while (i <= limit) [this[i],this[len-1-i++]] = [this[len-1-i],this[i]];
                         return this;
                       };

console.log(z.tRev()); // in place reversed
console.log(z1.tRev());
console.log(z2.tRev());
```

Incrementing the `i` thingy is just tricky though. That very position is the last call in array swap by ES6 array destructuring execution..

Comment: @Bergi OP's algorithm and the remaining answers under this topic count all the way to the end whereas this one counts only up to n/2 - 1. So there is that.. plus OP's code is not working properly. So what is the problem..?

Comment: Counting to n or n/2 doesn't make a difference for complexity.

Comment: @Bergi yes i know that... but not in my book. In my book the difference between O(2n) and O(n) is the same with O(n) and O(n/2).

Comment: Strange indentation.

Comment: @Redu: Exactly - no difference between any of them.

Comment: @Bergi Perfect... so let's assume this one to be O(n) and the others O(2n)